# java - Class whose name is known at compile time and which extends other class at runtime

Tags: java

I wish to create an open source implementation (subclass) of a propriertary adapter (super)class. I have two distinct requirements:

1. I need to extend the subclass at runtime, not at compile time
2. The class name of my subclass must be known at compile time.

Use case: since the superclass has a propriertary license, I cannot include its source nor reference a prebuilt binary in my open source project's build. The actual runtime usage of my subclass will occur in proprietary, closed-source framework code. This framework will create an instance of my subclass by name. For that reason, my subclass name needs to be known in advance.

The latter issue seems to preclude approaches like cglib which create a new class name at runtime.

Example code:

```
package com.proprietary;
public class Adapter {}

package org.free;
public class AdapterImpl
    // com.proprietary is not available at compile time
    // extends com.proprietary.Adapter 
{}

package com.proprietary;
public class Framework {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Simplified: class name is not hard-coded in reality,
         // but comes from external config
         Class c = Class.forName("org.free.AdapterImpl");
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Can reflections library help you, I wonder?

Comment: Can you change the propriertary adapter superclass into an interface, or make it use a strategy pattern so you don't have to extend it? With the dynamic proxy API, you can create implementations of interfaces at run time

Comment: @Joni: clear, but how do I get dynamic proxy API to create a fixed class name, so I can configure that to be used by com.propriertary.Framework from my example code?

Comment: The framework wouldn't use a class name, you would pass in an implementation of the interface instead. Are you the author of this framework or is it out of your control?

Comment: It's out of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe check out [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net).

You can "make" a new class dynamically, with features that can help support your constraints:

- Using `Class.forName` to load the third party proprietary class without linking to it in your code, you pass the class name as a configuration point
- [Naming strategy](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.6.9/net/bytebuddy/ByteBuddy.html#namingStrategy) gives you control on the name of generated class
- `intercept(`[Implementation](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.6.9/net/bytebuddy/implementation/Implementation.html)`)` to insert your custom code.

Example:

```
Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Class.forName(thatPeskyProprietaryClass))
  .namingStrategy(...)
  .method(ElementMatchers.named("someMethod"))
  .intercept(...)
  .make()
  .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
  .getLoaded();
```

Comment: this looks promising, as the naming strategy would allow me to influence (and hence make known in advance) the generated class name. I'll give it a try and update this post! Thanks!

Comment: ByteBuddy solved the problem easily. I could even specify a hard-coded name "org.free.AdapterImpl" as NamingStrategy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are going down the **wrong** rabbit hole.

First of all, this is not possible: you can't **extend** a class at runtime. The nature of a class is "fixed" at compile time; and then a .class file is written that contains that "nature". This can't be changed afterwards. Class C has class C; and you can't "enhance" C at runtime to say `C extends D` all of a sudden.

Beyond that: making a **subclass** only makes sense when you intend to exploit polymorphism.

Meaning:

```
class A { }
class B extends A {}
```

makes sense ... when your "client code" deals with both class names, A and B (most of the time).

So unless we are talking about some framework, where "your" objects need to extend A to allow integration in that framework, there is not much *benefit* from forcing your B to extend A "later on". Because as said: within your source code (compiler view) B would not be an A; so you couldn't write **any** code that benefits from B extending A.

So, the "closest" thing I can see here: use **composition**. Your class should contain a field pointing to an instance of that library class; and that instance is created using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

And then **your** class provides a nice, clean interface to access the behavior that can be found in A.

Comment: I suspect they need to pass a "customized" instance of `com.proprietary.Adapter` to third party code that expects this.

Comment: @GhostCat: yes, my subclass needs to extend the proprietary adapter to allow integration into a framework, which never deals with my class name directly, but uses the superclass (adapter) as a common interface. My code example is simplified in that com.proprietary.Framework has my class name hard-coded in the example, but that's not really the case. In reality, my class name comes from external configuration. The framework doesn't know it.

Comment: Got it. I am glad that you received a more direct answer pointing out more of a solution.